# block android automatic hyperlinking

Tags: java, android, html, email

I'm working on a Java Emailer App that harvests some numbers and wraps them in some html before sending it out to my team.  My problem is very specific to Android's Email App and I do not have this problem with Gmail or any other email service.

An example String object:

```
"<td class='time' style='border:1px solid black;font-size:10pt;vertical-align:top;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;padding-right:3px;padding-top:1px;padding-left:3px;'>12:30 PM</td>"
```

What is happening is Android is hyperlinking all my times and dates and I have tried a variety of tags to wrap these in but they do not prevent it.  Is there a way to block these?

Comment: First thing I'd try is `<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">` in the `head`, but I don't know much about Android's email app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to make it unrecognizable as time or a date. Similar issues occur with phone numbers and addresses. Try using `&nbsp;` in between the words:

```
12:30&nbsp;PM
```

You could also try splitting it up within span or font tags:

```
<td class='time' style='border:1px solid black;font-size:10pt;vertical-align:top;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;padding-right:3px;padding-top:1px;padding-left:3px;'>12:<font>30</font> PM</td>
```

This is a common issue on iPhones also. [This article addresses additional workarounds](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices) specifically for hiding the links on an iPhone